# How to compare dates in c#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have two dates. One date is input and other is `DateTime.Now`. I have them in `mm/dd/yyyy` format, it can even be m/d/yy format also. Both dates are nullable i.e, datatype is `DateTime?`, since I can pass null also as input. Now I want to compare the two dates only with `mm/dd/yyyy` or `m/d/yy` format.

Answer (score 112):

If you have your dates in DateTime variables, they don't *have* a format.

You can use the [`Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) property to return a DateTime value with the time portion set to midnight. So, if you have:

```cs
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse("07/12/2011");
DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Now;

if(dt1.Date > dt2.Date)
{
     //It's a later date
}
else
{
     //It's an earlier or equal date
}
```

Comment: Better use `DateTime.Today` than `DateTime.Now.Date` if u don't need hours, minutes etc

Comment: @Piotr - good point - unless they also need to access hours/minutes/seconds as another part of the work.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Will this work for any date format? 
What about `yyyy/MM/dd` ?

Comment: @Arbaaz - once you've converted whatever *string* you have into a `DateTime`, then as I said in my answer, it no longer *has* a format. It has an internal representation, and the framework knows how to perform appropriate comparisons.

Answer (score 45):

If you have date in `DateTime` variable then its a `DateTime` object and doesn't contain any format. Formatted date are expressed as `string` when you call `DateTime.ToString` method and provide format in it.

Lets say you have two `DateTime` variable, you can use the compare method for comparision,

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 1, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime date2 = new DateTime(2009, 8, 2, 0, 0, 0);
int result = DateTime.Compare(date1, date2);
string relationship;

if (result < 0)
   relationship = "is earlier than";
else if (result == 0)
   relationship = "is the same time as";         
else
   relationship = "is later than";
```

Code snippet taken from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx).

Answer (score 14):

Firstly, understand that `DateTime` objects aren't formatted. They just store the Year, Month, Day, Hour, Minute, Second, etc as a numeric value and the formatting occurs when you want to represent it as a string somehow. You can compare `DateTime` objects without formatting them.

To compare an input date with `DateTime.Now`, you need to first parse the input into a date and then compare just the Year/Month/Day portions:

```
DateTime inputDate;
if(!DateTime.TryParse(inputString, out inputDate))
    throw new ArgumentException("Input string not in the correct format.");

if(inputDate.Date == DateTime.Now.Date) {
    // Same date!
}
```