# compare different type datetime column > now c#

Tags: c#

i have a datetime value and i compare to now.
I try to convert the two dates to int because are different type.

this is a my code:

```
Int64 NowDate = Convert.ToInt64(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss"));

return mylist.Where(f => Convert.ToInt64(f.DateStart.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss")) > NowDate).ToList();
```

it works but if your of day is 21.00.00 i have a problem, convert.toint64 remove the 00.00 and my number is < nowdate.

Comment: False assumption. A DateTime is a DateTime. There is no need to convert to int. Did you try _f.DateStart < DateTime.Now_ ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare dates in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592126/how-to-compare-dates-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

To compare two dates in C#, you don't have to do any type conversions.

You can just write

```
mydate < DateTime.Now
```

And it will work !

Because DateTime implements `IComparable`, that means you can compare two Dates between one another

Answer (score 0):

Converting the Datetime to string creates lots of problems. For me, you should keep the dates as date. And you should try a query like this :

```
return mylist.Where(f => f.DateStart> Datetime.Now).ToList();
```

If you want to compare only dates, you can use :

```
 return mylist.Where(f => f.DateStart.Date > Datetime.Now.Date).ToList();
```

Attention, if your DateStart field is nullable, it can throw an exception. In this case you should control null values.