# How to check the date if the date required is greater or less than the current date?

Tags: c#

I want to check the date if the date required is greater or less than the current date.

As current date is `05 Apr 2018` so I want to get `01 Sep 2017`. If the current date is after `01 Sep 2018` then i want `01 Sep 2018`.

Please guide me how to achieve this. Appreciated, if you could provide me guidance.

Comment: This sounds like basic date compare functionality, takes 2 seconds to google that:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: DateTime has >, <, <=, >=. Knowing that, it's a pretty straightforward task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare dates in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592126/how-to-compare-dates-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, 9, 1);
DateTime result = dt;
if(DateTime.Today <= dt)
    result = dt.AddYears(-1);
```

Comment: I can't put the year manually. It should be always 1 year ahead from current year. Month and date is fine. Can you please the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Not the most elegant but probably the simplest solution;

```
var result = Convert.ToDateTime("01/09/" + DateTime.Now.Year);
if (result > DateTime.Now) result = result.AddYears(-1);
```

Comment: I don't mean to be rude but this is a bad way of creating a DateTime when you could just as easily use the DateTime constructor. To show this I made a small program to get an average of the two different methods, creating over 100 million DateTimes for each. On average, the normal constructor created 1mil DateTimes in 860.6ms while the ToDateTime() completed in 1664.08ms. That means ToDateTime() is ~93.4% slower than the normal constructor, presumably due to the string manipulation involved. Almost twice that of the constructor! Again, don't take this in a mean way, I was just bored at work.