# How to compare two dates in same DataGridView column

Tags: c#, datagridview

How to compare dates in one `DataGridView` column. I use for loop to do this, but no luck.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgv.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    DateTime currDate = Convert.ToDateTime(dgv.Rows[i].Cells["End Date"].Value);

    //index[0] > index[1] 
    //2020-04-04  2020-04-10
    if (currDate > currDate)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("In Progress");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to compare date without time, then see this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/683037/how-to-compare-only-date-without-time-in-datetime-types-in-linq-to-sql-with-enti/683042

Comment: `if (currDate > currDate)`? Both have same value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592126/how-to-compare-dates-in-c-sharp

Comment: @SalahAkbari , i have already column with different dates value. , if there way to compare dates in same column with different dates.

Comment: Yes it possible but compare them how? A given date? Against each other? How?